# Конвертирование типов long to int*

Tags: c++, указатели, header, типы, int

Вопрос нубский, потому что питонист.
Имеется функция в хедере через extern C.

```
void init(int N, int *srs, int *dst);
```

Через класс применяю её:

```
class cp
{

  public:
  void Copy(int *src,int *dest,int size64)
      {
  #ifdef -//-
          -//-
  #else     
          init(size64,adr((int) src),adr((int) dest));//adr - private
  #endif
      }
```

Вызываю в main.cpp

```
cp cpf
cp.Copy(A_adr, in1adr, sifeof(file));
```

Выдает ошибку:
  initializing argument 2,3 of 'void init(int, long long int*, long long int*)' [-fpermissive] и invalid conversion from 'int' to 'long long int*' [-fpermissive]
Я понимаю, что ошибка типов, так как адреса представлены в виде long long(hex формат - 0x000А80С0), которые передаем в int функцию.
Как конвертировать данные типы или избежать ошибку с передачей? И правильно ли я вызываю в main свою функцию? Правильно ли использую указатели?

@AlexGlebe @VTT 
adr - private функция класса
private:
    int adr(int x) {return x < 0x0000CC00} //объявление больше, но пришлось вырезать
A_adr - адрес в hex(0x000А80С0) тип long long 
in1adr - long long тип, которому указателем указан адрес свой адрес hex
sifeof(file) - пока не будем трогать, так как там просто цифру указываю куска копирования. Воспроизводимый код не могу привести, так как этого не нужно для понимания.

Comment: напишите декларацию функции `adr` - угадывать тяжело. Преобразовывать типы вручную - это плохая идея.

Comment: Хотя тут нигде не определяется, что такое `adr`, `A_adr`, `in1adr`, `file`, сделано все явно неправильно. `sifeof(file)` практически наверняка делает не то, что вы думаете, что он делает. Таких кастований как `(int) src` в программе на С++ вообще быть не должно.  Приведите [mcve].

Comment: @VTT Не соглашусь на счёт кастований. Это как раз преобразование типов в функции  [пример](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12031302/convert-from-long-long-to-int-and-the-other-way-back-in-c/12031462) вот тут.

Comment: @Zolberg101, объясните нормально, что вам нужно сделать. И определитесь со своей функцией `init`: какая у нее сигнатура? В начале вопроса вы пишите `void init(int N, int *srs, int *dst)` в середине `void init(int, long long int*, long long int*)`. Вам стоило бы согласится с @VTT: там где можно использовать C++-style касты, лучше использовать именно их.

Comment: Да и вообще, кастить `int *` в `int` -- довольно странно. Может,  вы хотели *разыменовать* `src`: `*src`?

Comment: @Zolberg101, каст указателя к числу должен заставить задуматься о правильности происходящего. Расскажите, что вы хотите сделать

Comment: @eanmos Перечитайте снова. Я функцию описал. Далее приведена ошибка. Внимательнее просмотрите. Я и не согласен с VTT, потому что такой тип кастования применяется. А на счёт что нужно сделать - я указал прямо и прямые вопросы. Читайте.

Comment: @Zolberg101, вот именно: в сообщении об ошибке говорится, что функция имеет вид `void init(int, long long int*, long long int*)`, вы же пишите `void init(int N, int *srs, int *dst)`.

Comment: @eanmos , вот именно: я пытаюсь преобразовать типы, но этого не происходит. Может есть смысл использовать: cp.copy<long long>(-//-);?

Comment: @Zolberg101, вы что, просто поменяли типы в объявлении `init`? Просто покажите весь ваш код.

Comment: @goldstar_labs Всего лишь преобразовать типы. В исходном варианте они в long long в функции в int/int*

Comment: @Zolberg101, поймите, вы делаете очень странные вещи в коде. Как минимум преобразование `int *` в `int`. Скорее всего вы не понимаете происходящего,  и не понимаете того, что вам пишут в комментариях. Лучше опишите, что конкретно вы хотите сделать (может, вам вообще не нужно преобразовывать типы!). Что делает функция `init`, зачем нужен метод `Copy` и т. д. Приведите [минимальный воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @eanmos Я не могу привести пример, так как для этого нужно скинуть сюда минимум 10-к файлов по 1000 строк. 
Я пытаюсь всего лишь использовать в main функцию Copy класса cp из хэдера. В хэдере есть extern C с функцией, на которую ругается компилятор и которая используется в классе. Вся цепочка. Но из-за разницы в типах вылетают ошибки.

Comment: @Zolberg101 Пример должен быть **минимальным**, не надо сваливать сюда весь свой код. И должно быть описание ожидаемого поведения. А в текущем виде код делает непонятно что. А уж если непривередливый компилятор С++ с его слабой типизацией (который обычно с радостью дает вам прострелить ногу) начинает ругаться с `fpermissive`, то дело совсем плохо.

Comment: @VTT на счет компилятора согласен

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Разобрался. Функция copy копирует из одного участка памяти в другой кусок size(3 аргумент).
Проблема состояла из 2 вещей:
1)Вызов нужно делать с переопределением конечного типа:

```
cp.Copy(reinterpret_cast<int*> A_adr, reinterpret_cast<int*>in1adr, 64)
```

2)в Хэдере void init делать без указателей:

```
void init(int N, int srs, int dst);
```

После этого ошибка пропадает. Плюс ещё компилятор слабоват, но это другой вопрос.
П.с. Всем спасибо, кто откликнулся, а именно @VTT, @eanmos, @AlexGlebe,@goldstar_labs.
п.п.с. Если зашедшие сюда не поняли чего-то не поняли или не разобрались, попросите уточнения в комментах и тд, как люди, дизы ставить не обязательно.

Comment: я поставил минус и вопрос и в ответ, потому что оба непонятны. Ваше решение не является рабочим и не решает проблему (о которой вы не рассказали)

Comment: @goldstar_labs я спрашивал базовые типы и методы конвертации, работу с указателями, а не помощь по коду и тыкание в надежде что заведётся. Я четко задал вопросы и привёл пример, не понимаю что тут непонятного. Данное решение у меня заработало и опубликовано в надежде, что если будет схожая ошибка узкого направления, то один из методов решения.